# If have_post not available then ng-bind

Tags: php, angular, wordpress, ng-bind

Hope you all be safe in this time of crisis. I'm looking for a solution to program my theme.. I do sometimes have content in my wordpress however i also does via a json. I wrote something but its throwing basic WP errors.

I need something like this but code correctly:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
            <h3 class="h3">About {{ctrl.Coin.name}}</h3>

            <?php
              if ( have_posts()  && get_the_content() != '') {
                  while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/coindetail-content', get_post_type() );

                  endwhile; // End of the loop.
                } else {
                  echo '<p ng-bind-html="ctrl.Coin.descriptionhtml"></p>';
                }
                ?>
          </div>
```

Who can help me with this?

Regards Dutch

Answer (score 1):

Wrong function. You have to call have_posts() instead of have_post().

like:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'coins', //post type name
'posts_per_page' => -1
);


$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts() && $loop->post_content != '') {
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/coindetail-content', 'coins');
    endwhile; // End of the loop.
} else {
    echo '<p ng-bind-html="ctrl.Coin.descriptionhtml"></p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: It is almost fixed, it does show the wordpress content but not ng-bind. Is this maybe because of the title is in have_posts as well? Is must check the post (post_content??) description I guess.

Comment: you can use like - if ( have_posts()  && get_the_content() != '') {}

Comment: I add the some demo code with fix, I tried it's working for me. Please check

Comment: I do have the above code now but this doesnt work, it still ouputting my json data, check my original one

Comment: If your post/page content is empty then it will show  ng-bind-html json data. else page content

Comment: What will be the code if I doesnt work with a template-part but just cpt-ui post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211625/discussion-between-shivendra-singh-and-dutchsociety).